# I want to check if someone has permission to be kicked, but the answer is wrong

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

I use `msg.member.hasPermission('KICK_MEMBERS')`, but even if the author of the message doesn't have this permission, the answer is `true` instead of `false`.

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
channel = '858963360909099068';

module.exports ={
    name: 'kick',
    description: 'kick people',
    execute(msg, args) {

        let impostor = msg.mentions.members.first();
        const mod = msg.author;
        let botResponse;  

        if(msg.member.hasPermission('KICK_MEMBERS')){
            console.log('true');
            if(!impostor){
                botResponse = 'You need to tag the person that you want to kick !';
                impostor = 'Not specified';
            }
            else{
                botResponse = `${impostor} was kicked !`;
                impostor.kick();
            }
        }
        else{
            console.log('false');
            botResponse = 'You are not able to kick people !';
        }
        
        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#f9ae0e')
        .setTitle('Kick')
        .setDescription(botResponse)
        .addFields(
            { name: "Impostor", value: impostor},
            { name: "Member", value: mod}
        );

        msg.channel.send(embed);
}
}
```

This is the error:

```
TypeError: msg.member.hasPermission is not a function
```

I can't see what's wrong here, can you help me solve it?

Comment: Okey. I solve the problem. the role @everyone had the permission ADMINISTRATOR.

Answer (score 0):

You should change `msg.member.hasPermission('PERM')` to `msg.member.permissions.has('PERM')`

Comment: I tried this. Same problem. It is like it jumps over this if, but i don't know why... Any other suggestions ?